# Transforming information in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

So, I have 2 tables,
In the 1st table, there is an Information of users

```
user_id | name   
1       | Albert 
2       | Anthony
```

and in the other table, I have information
where some users have address information where it can either be home, office or both home and office

```
user_id| address_type | address
1      |  home        | a
1      |  office      | b
2      |  home        | c
```

and the final result I want is this

```
user_id | name    | home_address | office_address
1       | Albert  |   a          |   b
2       | Anthony |   c          | null
```

I have tried using left join and json_agg but the information that way is not readable,
any suggestions on how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two outer joins, one for the office address and one for the home address.

```
select t1.user_id, t1.name, 
       ha.address as home_address, 
       oa.address as office_address
from table1 t1
  left join table2 ha on ha.user_id = t1.user_id and ha.address_type = 'home'
  left join table2 oa on oa.user_id = t1.user_id and ha.address_type = 'office';
```

A solution using JSON could look like this

```
select t1.user_id, t1.name,
       a.addresses ->> 'home' as home_address,
       a.addresses ->> 'office' as office_address
from table1 t1
  left join (      
    select user_id, jsonb_object_agg(address_type, address) as addresses
    from table2
    group by user_id
  ) a on a.user_id = t1.user_id;
```

Which might be a bit more flexible, because you don't need to add a new join for each address type. The first query is likely to be faster if you need to retrieve a large number of rows.